# Can I override a method in RSpec for just one argument call

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I've got a feature enablement mechanism in a couple of projects (one using RSpec 1 with Rails 2, and one with RSpec 2/Rails 3) and I'm looking for a better way to override just one feature, without having to do anything with other features.  Ultimately I'm looking for a way to stub a method when it's called with a particular argument, and behave normally otherwise.

Close:

```
Project::Config.should_receive(:feature_enabled?).with('new_feature').any_number_of_times.and_return(true)
get :index # calls feature_enabled? for a few other features too

>> <Project::Config (class)> expected feature_enabled? with 'new_feature' but received it with 'some old feature'
```

Works, but I'm looking for something a little cleaner, particularly in cases where there might be a few before{} blocks at different levels enabling different features.

```
Project::Config.should_receive(:feature_enabled?).with('new_feature').any_number_of_times.and_return(true)
# expect any other calls
Project::Config.should_receive(:feature_enabled?).any_number_of_times
# I can't override any features here.  This is annoying if I try to set up expectations at a few different levels
get :index # might call feature_enabled? for a few features
```

This also fails:

```
Project::Config.stub(:feature_enabled?).with('new_feature').and_return(true)
get :index

>> undefined method `feature_enabled?' for Project::Config:Class
```

Ideally I'd be able to do something in one line that doesn't affect other feature_enabled? calls.  If there's something that just works for RSpec2 that's fine, since we'll update the other project at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I've found to calling through to the original method works thusly:

```
method = Project::Config.method(:feature_enabled?)

Project::Config.stub(:feature_enabled?).and_return do |arg|
  method.call(arg)
end

Project::Config.should_receive(:feature_enabled?).with('new_feature').and_return(true)
```

Comment: Awesome -- I have to store a little extra state during each run to keep track of multiple features that get overridden, but this is working perfect.  Thanks Daniel!

Comment: No problem. I am always looking for ways to clean this up, but alas, I have found nothing better yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a maybe slightly cleaner alternative available in RSpec 3:

```rb
allow(Project::Config).to receive(:feature_enabled?).and_wrap_original do |method, arg|
  case arg
  when 'new_feature'
    true
  else
    method.call(arg)
  end
end
```

If you know you only need the one case, then you can also use a ternary or even a simple `||`:

```rb
allow(Project::Config).to receive(:feature_enabled?).and_wrap_original do |method, arg|
  arg == 'new_feature' || method.call(arg)
end
```